# Zsh theme guides

Tags: zsh, theme

Does anyone know good tutorials (or books) for what goes into writing a theme?

Comment: What do mean by "theme"? a prompt theme?

Comment: @qbi is my meaning ambiguous in some way I don't realize? is there another kind of theme that I might be referring to?

Comment: actually I was thinking about colors and bolds and underlines when I read your question. I also thought "This might be another fancy feature of zsh". Am I being too much of a noob?

Comment: @phunehehe themes seem to basically be a way of encapsulating things like colors bolds in a redistributable way. But all in all it's just that. I'm thinking about turning my fancy-ish vim behavior into such a theme... but I need to know more about what's required and why/how.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Robbie Russell's Oh My Zsh project on Github - http://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

There's a bunch of theme's in there that should give you a fair amount of info.